# Why Contours ar not shown as blue after canny edge detection

Tags: image-processing, contour, emgucv, canny-operator

I want to find contours after canny edge detection. But they shown up in white color even though BGR is set as (255,0,0).
What is wrong in the code?

```
private void Capture_ImageGrabbed1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Mat m = new Mat();
        capture.Retrieve(m);
        pic1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;

        if(mode == 1)
        {

        var image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        var grayScaleImage = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        var blurredImage = grayScaleImage.SmoothGaussian(5, 5, 0, 0);
        var cannyImage = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(blurredImage, cannyImage, 10, 50);

        VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        CvInvoke.FindContours(cannyImage, contours, null, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
        CvInvoke.DrawContours(cannyImage, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0),2);

        pic2.Image = cannyImage.Bitmap;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

pic2.Image is the picturebox. Code is working but no blue contours as in attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPPYW.jpg)picture.

Comment: Likely `cannyImage` is a gray-scale image, so you can't draw in color into it.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo. I have corrected it as in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Capture_ImageGrabbed1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Mat m = new Mat();
        capture.Retrieve(m);
        pic1.Image = m.Bitmap;

        if(mode == 1)
        {

        var image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        var grayScaleImage = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        var blurredImage = grayScaleImage.SmoothGaussian(5, 5, 0, 0);
        var cannyImage = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(blurredImage, cannyImage, 10, 50);

        VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        CvInvoke.FindContours(cannyImage, contours, null, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
        var cannyOut = cannyImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        CvInvoke.DrawContours(cannyOut, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0),2);
        
        pic2.Image = cannyOut.Bitmap;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```